# UI-router abstract state with no url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

A way to define an abstract state using the UI-Router is as follows:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/blog/home');

  $stateProvider

  // abstract state
  .state('blog', {
    url: '/blog',
    templateUrl: '/templates/navbar.html',
    abstract: true,
    controller:'NavBarCtrl as navbar',
  })

  // home
  .state('blog.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
    controller:'HomeCtrl as home',
  })

 ...
})
```

When you navigate to the state home, you will however go to the domain:

```
yourcustomdomain.com/blog/home
```

Is there a way to define the url of the abstract state such that it does not show the prefix `blog`, thus:

```
yourcustomdomain.com/home?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove url from abstract state

```
.state('blog', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: '/templates/navbar.html',
  abstract: true,
  controller:'NavBarCtrl as navbar',
})
```